# What in mathematics has the property of beauty?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, aesthetics, semiotics, beauty

I might or might not be at an impasse in my writing... I have around 200 pages of notes, and I finally sat down and tried to compile some of the material, but I feel like the presentation is off somehow. There are so many details to go over, half the time it's like, "Where do I even start?" or even worse, "Am I forgetting some subargument that I need to go over before going over what I actually started with?"

At any rate, I'm assuming that implementations are the semiotic analogue of models and proofs re: semantics and syntax. So I want to codify what it is about them that might or might not at least partially/incompletely "justify" them, seeing as they do obscurely affect the space of theorems in a set theory.

I was also considering alternative formulations of intuitionism. I actually have assimilated Cantor to a technical alternative intuitionism, namely a theological one, where God, Who is all-powerful, certainly has the power to cause mathematicians to have intuitive knowledge of various things, here the mathematical realm. (To be sure/fair, I don't know whether Cantor thought that God had intuitively or discursively revealed the alephs and the omegas to him. But at any rate, God's own knowledge being a matter of intellectual intuition (as per Kant), God's knowledge of the mathematical realm is intuitive, so we still have an intuitionism in possible play, here.)

However, there is also the question of aesthetic judgment in mathematics. In my eyes, the property of beauty, such as it is (it might be a relation, IDK, I haven't read/thought enough about it to be honest), is intuitively given. Even if there is some arcane/convoluted process involving the mental gears of our Kantian faculty psychology, that is meant by the notion of beauty, yet if I remember correctly, since it is the power of judgment that is implicated in the process, and judgment is the vehicle of subsuming particular intuitions under general concepts, so this ends up sounding like 'knowledge' of beauty is interchangeable with an intuition of something as beautiful.

Now I suppose that's all unnecessary to the actual intended argument on this score, because my intent is to advert to aesthetic considerations as justifying conditions modulo semiotics, and it doesn't matter *too* much whether aesthetic consciousness is principally intuitive or discursive, or somehow both, or whatever. Although semiosis is a more intuitive process, on the surface, than syntactic configuration (which seems almost the *sine qua non* of discursion), it is irrelevant to the immediate argument whether it is also strongly discursive a process for some reason.

So my question is: **'where' is beauty in the mathematical realm?**

I read through a Wikipedia article that covered this topic, and the article seemed to indicate that different things on different levels count as mathematically beautiful: a simple proof, a clever proof, etc. However, I want to focus on a paradigmatic example in order to illustrate what might or might not be at stake with respect to Benacerraf's implementation problems. This example is Euler's identity, normally stated as:

> e<sup>*i*π</sup> + 1 = 0

IIRC, the Wikipedia article cited an opinion that part of/the reason for this being such a beautiful equation is that it showcases a deep relationship between various numbers that are fundamentally important to the development of the theory of arithmetic and other such functions on numbers. However, this makes the fact that the inscription refers to into the thing that is beautiful: it is beautiful that e<sup>*i*π</sup> + 1 = 0.

So consider the following list of alternative statements of the very same fact:

> e<sup>π*i*</sup> + 1 = 0

> 1 + e<sup>π*i*</sup> = 0

> 0 = 1 + e<sup>π*i*</sup>

> 2.71,,,<sup>3.14...(√-1)</sup> + 1/1 = 0

> *The natural logarithm, when raised to the power of the imaginary unit (which itself is multiplied first by the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter), and then added to 1, equals zero.*

> *I dór ceri-, ir na i rod plural rodyn -o i pennas er bui i in -o a rind's os- na i thar, a a er, na- lost.* {This is an extremely frustrating Sindarin translation of the preceding. Don't try translating it back: to find words that would go through on the program, I had to rephrase the preceding by more or less 'literally' butchering it.}

> (e ↑<sup>3</sup> (*i* ↑<sup>2</sup> π)) ↑<sup>1</sup> 1 = 0

> (e ↑<sup>3</sup> ((-1 ↓<sup>3</sup> 2) ↑<sup>2</sup> π)) ↑<sup>1</sup> 1 = 0

There is a supposition, on my part, that issues of glyphic efficiency are implicated in the display of glyphic elegance. The simplest efficient digitalization of the natural numbers is in binary format (i.e. having two symbols, whose concatenations 'stand in for' 2, 3, 4, ...), and for all the good it would do (and it might do some good!), we could then trade out the zeroes and 1's for F's and T's (for False and True), so then even ⊥ and ⊤, maybe. Certainly Cantor made an eternally wise choice by using the aleph glyph, and indeed subitizing the set of all natural numbers is most efficiently accomplished by having a unit symbol for infinity, then (though note that, if we are not to have a different glyph for every transfinite cardinal, we have to index our unit symbol to differentiate the cardinals to at least some extent (note that even inaccessible cardinals and their initial ordinals can be styled fixed points of the aleph/omega functions, after all)).

Kant said something somewhere about clarity of understanding being a matter of appreciating the distinctions between things: a term is clear when clearly differentiated from other terms. I assume there are possible glyphsets that satisfy this criterion to the minimally satisfactory extent, that is they have the minimum number of elements (glyphs) required to clearly differentiate the terms of the system. But I don't think this has to result in a more beautiful display of mathematics than if we used more glyphs, or rather I don't see why this simple efficiency would be the only criterion of mathematical beauty.

"Bonus points": and don't get me started on Kant's theory of the sublime as a counterpoint to beauty, what with his talk (if I recall) of the ratio of finitude to infinity. I would say that the finitist thinks we 'merely' lack justification for asserting an actual infinity as an individual 'number,' whereas the ultrafinitist goes further and says that those infinitarian assertions are **anti**justified, but then neither of these analysts would be able to believe in infinitely beautiful equations/theorems/what-have-you. And ultrafinitism, by conceptually 'destroying' an infinite amount of possible beauty (so to say), convicts itself of its own antijustification, however: in fact, ultrafinitism turns out to be *infinitely grotesque.*

Comment: "*While on the Platonist conception the experience of mathematical beauty consists in an intellectual insight into the fundamental structures of the universe, according to the Kantian proposal the experience of beauty in mathematics is grounded in our felt awareness of the imaginative processes that lead to mathematical knowledge*", [Breitenbach, Beauty in Proofs](http://angelabreitenbach.weebly.com/uploads/5/7/5/7/57579773/breitenbach-beautyproofs.pdf). See also [Blasjo, A Definition of Mathematical Beauty and Its History](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/vol2/iss2/8/).

Comment: @Kristian Berry I understand the title of your question. But unfortunately I cannot follow your long explication. Could you please condense your argumentation to a compact form? Thanks.

Comment: @JoWehler, I feel like I've seen people say something about beauty contributing to truth in mathematics. If this is just a matter of proofs, then in light of the up-and-up among logical pluralists and multiverse set theorists, which seem jointly to allow one to prove anything at all, I wonder how that would be so. However, when framing the issue of mathematical beauty in semiotic terms, I only have a weak, and seemingly incomplete, standard (glyphic efficiency). So where do I go?

Comment: Re your "whether aesthetic consciousness is principally intuitive or discursive, or somehow both, or whatever", imagine for some discursive 1-st grade topics you completely understand them all, then whether concentrated intuitive or casual discursive consciousness no longer matters, you can have a clear judgement of the beauty of any such topic. So it's the discursive *completeness*, *connectedness* and intuitive finite *compactness* of your mind matter. In summary intuition is not the source of beauty of anything including math (if any at all) which may only be peeked via true wisdom..

Comment: @DoubleKnot, I often am conscious of something as beautiful before sustained reflection on that thing. Most especially, the emotional state known as *saudade* has always seemed, in fact not just beautiful, but sublime too, or even beyond those categories (partaking of glory, perhaps, as something superlative over those?). While discursive analysis of this emotion has actually intensified it in ways, in other ways it is ever always as intense now as before, so IDK.

Comment: Saudade/Nostalgia was hinted in Meno regarding the knowledge paradox Socrates proposed that we already know what we need to know, ie, the doctrine of recollection of the soul. Perhaps certain glyphs and forms strongly attract your soul yet you didn't fully understand them like 1st grade ostensive topics. For someone with complex analysis background knowledge, Euler's identity is a very basic 180 degree counterclockwise rotation brute fact in the Argand plane, very brute not beautiful at all, while when people were not familiar with what imaginary number is it seems mysterious and beautiful...

Comment: Why does something being "very basic" detract from its beauty? The Cartesian grid doesn't come preloaded with its numerical interpretation; the idea of zero being the center of the grid is not a trivial one, I think, but it is basic and yet, is it not beautiful in its own way? (Or rather, the fact that zero is the origin is beautiful in its own way, to me.) On another level, though, I would say that the flow of the notation in transfinite set theory, especially when the aleph and beth glyphs are used, is more beautiful, to me, than (most of) the flow of finite-reference notation.

Comment: For example, the periodicity graph(?) modulo the Levy hierarchy (I assume that's what it is, it's something Maddy talks about in terms of a possible "zigzag" image (I think she even goes over the topic in aesthetic terms at some point)).

Comment: In primitive societies when language symbols were first created, the illiterate would find them beautiful in awe while only a very small portion of people had the means to actually learn and master them. Later when most people in society could learn and manage them via reading and writing, the sublime and awe of symbols qua themselves got diminished gradually, on the contrary, the exploit of language symbols began to rise. What makes one feel beautiful is the transition struggling stage to learn them but not entirely mastered them yet...

Comment: I still find individual letters and symbols to be beautiful even when I know and understand them, not only with respect to more complex symbols but even just font/typeface variations (Fraktur Latin letters, for instance). IDK, I guess I think that if I'm going to be a logical pluralist and a multiverse set-theorist to some extent, I can hardly be more monistic about aesthetics.

Comment: Regarding the above said "beauty" in font/typeface variations, it's primary due to their usage *satisfy* certain pluralistic *intention* or *mood* of either a reader or the author, since either intention or mood is highly subjective based on more basic singular brute facts. G.E.M. Anscome termed *brute* facts, not *beautiful* facts though... Once a reader feels beauty in a plurality of things, she or he will certainly be motivated to continue to read...

Comment: Surprisingly Freud had a famous culminating concept called [death drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_drive) which metaphysically posits that the mastery of any skill is under the pressing drive of death which is *an urge in organic life to restore an earlier state of things"-the inorganic state from which life originally emerged... and the resulting "separation of the death instincts from the life instincts" seen in Eros. The death drive then manifested itself in the individual creature as a force "whose function is to assure that the organism shall follow its own path to death"...*

Comment: *...such evidence led Freud "to justify the hypothesis of a compulsion to repeat—something that would seem more primitive, more elementary, more instinctual than the pleasure principle which it over-rides"..."to err is human, to persist [in committing such errors] is of the devil"...Freud seemed to have landed in the position of Schopenhauer, who taught that 'death is the goal of life'...* So under this theory, beauty arises when the "will to live" dominates, but once you fully mastered under the drive of "will to destruction", eros fades which is also consistent with what I commented before..

Comment: The Thanatos/mortudo concept kind of shows up in my ethical system, but I think the initial 'derivation' is juxtaposed with an abstract question in environmental ethics, and only adapted 'down the road' to questions of specific mass atrocities like the Holocaust (to say nothing of the suicidal side of mortudo modulo Freud's introduction of the concept). All that being said, I don't know how much Freud I would have cause to cite in the essay I'm working on otherwise.

Comment: Freud's 3 egos and death drive speculations have compelling arguments, for the intellectual goal to learn knowledge is not to enjoy it once but to master it correctly such that when one encounters similar problem with same schemata pattern one can immediately apply it to become useful according to the *pleasure principle* of *id* like a precision machine, which is a perfect repetition-compulsion instance. So mastering means drive to death-like hard determinism without any possible modality...This may be why Adam and Eve were warned in the garden about the tree of knowledge due to such drive...